# FFMPEG - Insert text MP4 and closed

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using FFmpeg to insert text in a video. However I did not want it ENCODED The Full Video . Just as I want the text to be inserted at 20 seconds, then I want to stop coding. Since I'll encode several videos a day.
I just need to add the text and do NOT need to to read entire video.

Next I use the command , only that it encodes the Full Video .

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -strict experimental -vf "drawtext=fontfile='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf':text='Liberado para Celso':x=500:y=10:fontsize=9" saida3.mp4
```

I believe I don't need to generate a MP4 as output, just that it inserts the text and be fast!

Comment: what text are you trying to insert? also, please try to follow correct format and syntax when asking on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide a more detailed example of what your are trying to achieve.

Comment: I need a text to be inserted into a video 30minutes . But this compilation is quick, only enter the text and do not have to compile the entire video as does the FFMEG.